# Sorting in Python 3.3

Tags: python, sorting, file-io, casting, int

I am trying to sort a list of 100 two-digit integers brought in from a file and for some reason the sorted() function seems to make no changes. I have already searched similar issues with the sorted function and most of them are because there is no typecast to an int which I have included. Please let me know where my logic is failing.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import copy

data = []
with open('afile.txt') as file:
for line in file:
    line = line.split() # to deal with blank 
    if line:            # lines (ie skip them)
        line = [int(i) for i in line]
        data.append(copy.copy(line))
newdata = sorted(data)
print(newdata)
```

EDIT:

Input is simply a one to two digit number and a space between them.
Ex.  17 8 97 1 26

Comment: How is your input formatted? Can you [edit] an example (say 5 or 6 integers) into the question?

Comment: `data` is a list of lists.. what do you expect sorting to do to it?

Comment: In this code, `data` is a list of lists. Change `data.append` to `data.extend` and see if you get better results.

Comment: Thanks all, didn't realize I created a list of lists.

Comment: Side note: you don't need to use the `copy` module to copy the list. In python3 `list` has a `copy()` method that returns a copy of the list. Alternatively just doing `list(an_other_list)` will create a copy. A more obscure (and shorter) way is to use slicing: `some_list[:]` will create a copy (the `[:]` means take a slice from the beginning to the end, since the `start` and `stop` parameters were omitted.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

data ends up being a list of lists, are you sure that's what you want?

Perhaps replace

```
data.append(copy.copy(line))
```

with

```
data.extend(line)
```

Are there multiple lines each with multiple numbers on them?

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot. +Rep for when I can (Can't as of now until I earn some of my own).

Comment: @Demosthanes - after a few minutes you'll be able to accept the answer, which will also give you some rep. Also, if it's one number per line (as referred to in gnibbler's closing question) you can use `data.append(int(line.strip()))` - you would generally use `split` to turn something like `"5 7 10"` into a list `["5", "7", "10"]` before calling `int` on each string. So it depends on your actual input.